# Issue with OpenLDAP as PRIMARY external user store setup for Wso2is 5.8.0: get "error 21" related to createTimestamp attribute" when adding new user

Tags: docker-compose, ldap, wso2, openldap, wso2-identity-server

I have almost the same problem discuss in the question below, but I get error at the claim configuration step :

[Unable to setup OpenLDAP as primary user store for wso2is 5.6.0: LDAP Error 65 when adding a new user in management console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879953/unable-to-setup-openldap-as-primary-user-store-for-wso2is-5-6-0-ldap-error-65-w)

I want to setup Wso2is-5.8.0 with OpenLDAP as Primary user store and I use a Docker-Compose file for the deployment.

The connection step between Identity Server and Openldap ended successfuly, I have got all my LDAP user in IS and the admin user has been added to LDAP. Now I'm configuring the claim parameters.

I defined :

urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:meta.resourceType = http://wso2.org/claims/userType

I get "err=17 text=userType: attribute type undefined"
So I defined userType as below:

http://wso2.org/claims/userType = Users (related to the "ou" value in OpenLDAP)

Then I get "err=17 text=createdDate: attribute type undefined"
So I defined createdDate as below:

http://wso2.org/claims/created = createTimestamp (as attribute name in OpenLDAP)

And now I get :

```
5d14d9a9 conn=1168 op=2 ADD dn="uid=usertest,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=org"
5d15dd6e conn=1340 op=2 RESULT tag=105 err=21 text=createTimestamp: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

I try checking Read only in "Created Time" claim configuration but same error.

Does anyone have a way to solve this problem?

I attached below my user-mgt.xml file.

Thank you in advance

```
<UserManager>
  <Realm>
    <Configuration>
    <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
    <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
    <AdminUser>
        <UserName>admin</UserName>
        <Password>admin</Password>
    </AdminUser>
    <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName>
    <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
    <!-- Enable username claim retrieve from the UM_USER_NAME in JDBC datasources-->
        <OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>true</OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>
    <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
    <Property name="initializeNewClaimManager">true</Property>
    <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2IdentityDS</Property>
    </Configuration>
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
      <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://192.168.1.10:389</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin</Property>
      <Property name="AnonymousBind">false</Property>
      <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=Users,dc=example,dc=org</Property>
      <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">inetOrgPerson</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=?))</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)</Property>
      <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
      <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
      <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
      <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=org</Property>
      <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">posixGroup</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=posixGroup)(=?))</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=posixGroup)</Property>
      <Property name="MembershipAttribute">memberUid</Property>
      <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._\-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
      <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._\-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
      <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
      <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
      <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.ORG</Property>
      <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
      <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
      <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
      <Property name="StartTLSEnabled">false</Property>
    </UserStoreManager>
    <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
      <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
      <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property>
    </AuthorizationManager>
    <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
      <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
      <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2UM_DB</Property>
      <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
      <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
      <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
      <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
      <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
      <Property name="CaseInsensitiveUsername">false</Property>
      <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
      <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
      <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
      <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
      <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
      <Property name="LeadingOrTrailingSpaceAllowedInUserName">false</Property>
    </UserStoreManager>
  </Realm>
</UserManager>
```

Comment: After many tries, I realize that I had misunderstantood the "Claim" function.I am not supposed to modify the value in " http://wso2.org/claims/userType " because this claims will be used to make the mapping with others identity provider and service provider. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this after restarting,

1. After starting the Identity server go to Home -> Identity -> Claims
   -> List.
2. Select “urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0” and then click edit on “urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:meta.resourceType”.
3. For “Mapped Local Claim” select a appropriate claim you would like to map to this. For e.g : http://wso2.org/claims/userType and
   click update.

You can read more on configuring OpenLDAP with WSO2 IS in https://medium.com/@gdrdabarera/how-to-configure-open-ldap-with-wso2-identity-server-5-4-0-3a76bf240001

Comment: Thank you for response.As mentionned in my question, I get some troubles just after this resolution attempt.

Comment: I'm using identity server 5.6 and got this issue while creating user. but when I mapped the resourceType with userType I got an error as "userType is undefined" so i tried mapping with http://wso2.org/claims/userName local claim and it worked without any error. Is there any reason behind that?

Answer (score 0):

This resourceType claim is introduced in IS-5.4.0. From this onwards, In WSO2 IS for representing the resourceType we have mapped an LDAP attribute called "ref", but it seems "ref" is an attribute that's reserved in OpenLDAP for referrals. As a workaround for this issue “urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:meta.resourceType” was mapped to userType claim in this question [Unable to setup OpenLDAP as primary user store for wso2is 5.6.0: LDAP Error 65 when adding a new user in management console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879953/unable-to-setup-openldap-as-primary-user-store-for-wso2is-5-6-0-ldap-error-65-w). This question was asked based on IS 5.6.0 and We were able to observe this issue  from IS 5.4.0 onwards.

But this issue was fixed in latest released Identity Server 5.8.0 as a fix for this issue https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/4807. In the latest version, http://wso2.org/claims/resourceType claim is mapped to "resourceType" attribute. You can check this in claim-config.xml file located in the directory /repository/conf/. So you don't need to map the "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:meta.resourceType" to any local claims such as "http://wso2.org/claims/userType" claim. Hence no need to change the mapped attribute of resourceType claim.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So, I restarted everything from the begining. I configure my OpenLDAP as the PRIMARY user store from the user-mgt.xml file. The connection to the managment interface goes well. The users from OpenLDAP appears here as expected. And when I try to add user I get the classic error " cannot acces the directory context or user already exists .." and in the OpenLDAP logs I get : "... err=17 text=scimId: attribute type undefined" . Where this error comes from? Should I configure something in the Claims part or maybe in the repository/conf/identity/identity.xml file ?

Comment: I have also try to edit a user profil that comes from the LDAP. I get the following error : "One or more attributes you are trying to add/update are not supported by underlying LDAP" + when trying to change password I get : "Error updating SCIM metadata in doPostUpdateCredentialByAdmin listener". It seems that the identity structures of WSO2 and the LDAP user store do not matched at all.